# Are there any typesafe printing function in matlab that accept multiple inputs?

Tags: matlab, stream

I have finally started to get tired on matlabs printout function. I mean `disp` is really good for a single output since it implements the printout that is defined for each object. However, what if want more than one printout. Let us say that I want to print a struct and a double.

```
a.q=1; a.r.t=2;
disp(1,a); %Crash! too many input arguments.
```

what output I want from a function call `dispfcn(1,a)` would really be something like

```
1, a:[1x1 struct] % or
1, [1x1 struct] %or
1, a.q=1, a.r % let us keep values to first level or
1, a.q=1
   a.r
```

or anything really. The thing is that I am prepared to let matlab decide. For now I can manage with

```
disp({1,a})
```

but, this look ugly and will enclose all my text with `[]`

```
disp({'turn:',1,'a:',a})
```

it also gives the impression that I deal with separate values, which is not good. The best would be if there would exist an output stream in matlab. That would make things easy: eg

```
stream s = [];
stream.add('turn: 1',1);
...
s.print; %or disp(s)?
```

or

```
stream s = stream('turn: ', 1, ...
disp(s);
```

Does anyone know if there is a stream in matlab that can be printed or if there would be a function `fcn` that can return `out = 'a:[1x1 struct]'` for a call

```
out=fcn(a);
```

Comment: You could modify the function diginto until it fits to your demands: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21946-diginto

Comment: @BerndGit Thanks for your answer but since I prefer an output `a:[1x1 struct]` for more than one outputs, I could generate a one liner `out = [ inputnames(1), ':', '[', num2str( size(varargin{1},1) ), 'x', num2str( size(varargin{1},2) ), ']' ]` doing what I want there. But assume that I then want to do it for cells, classes, sorry it will not hold. For the single input case, `disp` work excellent.

Comment: Yes. This is my suggestion. You might want to use the 'isa' function to check the type of your input variable.  Altogether this might cause some programming effort but not too much.  you can additionally use ´try catch' constructs to avoid runtime errors for not-implemented types

Comment: @BerndGit I see, I admit that I had forgot about all these class functions. There is actually a function `class` that can find the class name should be able to keep the code short, however, while this is fairly safe it is not completely type safe. So thanks for the tip, I will implement that, but it would feel a lot better if matlab would have created a dips function that could take a stream or multiple inputs, that is officially type safe.